# On complexity of linear programming with quadratic equality/inequality constraints?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, ds.algorithms, linear-programming, polynomial-time, convex-optimization

Feasibility test in Linear programming is in $P$ and in convex quadratic programming is in $P$. What is the maximum $k$ such that $n$-variable $m=poly(n)$ linear constraint feasibility test with $k$ many quadratic (not necessarily convex constraints)

1. equality constraints in $P$?
2. inequality constraints in $P$?

> Can $k=\Omega(poly(n))$ hold in both cases? At least can $k>0$ hold at least for $1.$?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A famous result by Motzkin and Straus expresses the $k$-clique problem as the maximization of a quadratic function subject to a system of linear constraints.  In particular, they prove:

> Let $G$ be a graph with vertices $1,\ldots,n$ and edge set $E$. 
>   Then $G$ contains a $k$-clique,
>   **if and only if** there exist real numbers $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ 
>   that satisfy the quadratic constraint
>   $$\sum_{(i,j)\in E}x_ix_j \ge \frac12\left(1-\frac1k\right)$$
>   together with the linear constraints $\sum_{i=1}^nx_i=1$ 
>   and $x_1,\ldots,x_n\ge0$.

- Since the $k$-clique problem is NP-hard, this implies that feasibility testing for a linear program plus a single quadratic **inequality** constraint is NP-hard.
- If the graph $G$ contains a $k$-clique $C$, then for $i\in C$ we may set $x_i=1/k$ and for $i\notin C$ we may set $x_i=0$. 
  Note that the resulting point $x$ satisfies all constraints in the feasibility problem with equality. 
  This yields that also feasibility testing for a linear program plus a single quadratic **equality** constraint is NP-hard.

Reference:
T.S. Motzkin and E.G. Straus (1965), "Maxima for graphs and a new proof of a theorem of Turán." Canadian Journal of Mathematics 17, pp 533–540.

Comment: Does the same argument work for GI on why I cannot solve GI by just $PGP′=H$ on constraint permutation $P$ is generated by linear constraints $$\forall i: \sum_{j = 1}^n{P_{ij}} = 1$$
$$\forall j: \sum_{i = 1}^n{P_{ij}} = 1$$
$$\forall i, j: P_{ij} \geq 0$$ where $G$ and $H$ are adjacency matrices of graphs whose isomorphisms need to be tested?.

Comment: For a permutation matrix $P$, you can write $PG = HP$ instead of $PGP^T = H$. This gives a linear program together with the constraint you give, and you can solve it. But the solution will be a doubly stochastic matrix $P$, not necessarily a permutation matrix. While you can write a doubly stochastic $P$ as a convex combination of permutation matrices, there is no guarantee any of them will be an isomorphism.